# Windows server 2008 base image for docker

Tags: windows, docker, windows-server-2008

I used docker on Windows server 2016 which runs containers natively. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/deploy-containers-on-server) I could see only 2 base images available: *windowsservercore* and *nanoserver*.

From what I understand both of them are like a fraction of Windows Server 2016. **Or are they?**

I have a specific version of my application that runs only on Windows server 2008. I was wondering if there was a base image of windows server 2008? Or will there be one in the future?

Comment: There is no such thing as base image for Windows Server 2008. As you understand correctly, there is just two base images, `windowsservercore` and `nanoserver`. Both are striped down version of Windows Server 2016. So, upgrade your application to run on Windows server 2016 and then run in container.